# Python 2.7 print statement “SyntaxError: expected indented block”

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error, block, indentation

I am using Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

I am getting a syntax error stating that it is expecting a indented block. I heard that Python checks white spaces and that they have to be "aligned"? I would appreciate any answers and links. I installed matplotlib and numpy by the way.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX () :
date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt'), unpack=True,
                          delimiter=',',
                          converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

ax1.plot(date,bid)
ax1.plot(date,ask)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: "How do I Python?" This is asked 1,000 times per day here. Please search before asking, etc. I have already found the answer three times just looking through the Related links on the sidebar.

Comment: OK, I understand. Is there an existing question similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong tutorial. Not that it matters in this case, but you are linking to the introduction for Python 3.4.

Your mistake is that you dont indent your code after `def graphRawFX():`

Try this instead:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX () :
    date,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt'), unpack=True,
                 delimiter=',',
                 converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Note: I believe the number of spaces / tabs you are indenting is irrelevant as long as it is the same for each block, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: It still says the same expected indented block but tell me how I can tell indenting is needed? I don't want to ask every time or I'll lose reputation as I just did.

Comment: The interpreter decides how much indentation based on the file format. Just be consistent. If you indent with two spaces, always indent with two spaces. If you indent with a tab (which is different than a space!), always indent with a tab. Just **be consistent**. And [read PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). And [PEP 20](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

Comment: An indent is needed everytime you create a new block. That is mostly after conditions (`if`,  `elif` and `else`), loops (`for` and `while`), method and function definitions (like you did) and class definitions.

Comment: @jrg Yes, so you indent to distinguish but the code you posted still gives the error. Really annoying.

Comment: I would try to change the line starting with `dat,bid,ask` and unwrap it a bit more eg. split it to several lines